# How to recover lambda code or edit it inline after uploading huge sized zip file to the aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Firstly, I am a newbie to AWS. I was able to edit my Lambda code in line, but I recently uploaded a zip file to it(30MB) to S3 bucket and added this zip to my Lambda from S3, and now my Lambda inline editor doesn't open anymore saying the following error

> "The deployment package of your Lambda function "LF2" is too large to
>   enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function."

I tried deleting my zip file from S3 bucket hoping that the URL of zip would not be reachable and the lambda would lose the zip file and let me edit the function again. But, my lambda size still consists of the 30MB zip file size. I am unable to delete this zip and can't figure out a way to get rid of this it and edit my lambda code again.

Note: My Lambda code was written in-line and different from the zip file(which only contains elastic search setup files which I uploaded for using in my code since import elastic search wasn't working). I know there would have been a better way to do this without uploading it's zip.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I just ran into same soup .. seem like the upload replaced the previous index.js with export handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can download the Lambda function. Go to the AWS console for the Lambda function, make sure you are in the Configuration view, then click Actions | Export function. This will allow you to download a ZIP file containing the Lambda function.

Note that once you upload a Lambda function via S3, it's copied by the Lambda service. There's no connection at that point back to the S3 object that you uploaded. One reason for this is that your Lambda function would break if you, accidentally or otherwise, deleted the file from S3.

[image]

Comment: This downloads only the zip file which I uploaded, not my Python Lambda code. I need to edit my Python code in line or atleast retrieve the code. How do i do it?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation jarmod about how lambda service copies s3 object. But, I have updated my description with a note. I am not uploading my lambda via S3, I had my lambda code in line and I just tried uploading the elasticsearch library zip file via s3 since 'import elasticsearch' wasn't working.

Comment: The ZIP file that you uploaded to Lambda becomes your new Lambda function, replacing the previous one. If it's not actually a valid function, that's immaterial, unfortunately. Do you have a backup of the original source code?

Comment: Sad, I didn't know it would replace my code, I thought it was there to add any external dependencies or so. Unfortunately, I don't have any backup since I didn't expect this. Seems I may to do it all again :( Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I know that's painful. I can't think of an obvious way to recover the source if you don't have a backup of it. That said, be aware that if you develop outside of the Lambda console then you can easily package and deploy into Lambda. And if you code within the Lambda console then you can export the code (per above). You can also enable versioning on the Lambda function but that's not really a solution to the problem you ran into (because it's related to publishing functions, not making simple code changes).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday then I somehow managed to find my code but not that full code that was **vanished** from AWS lambda. I wrote that code again, tested it, then tried to upload it with the same name of the lambda function and at the same lambda function by compressing it in my own system.

While uploading it, lambda gave me the option to choose between the remote file I uploaded and the local file it had saved previously. I opted for the **local file** and boom! I got my code back as it was last saved.

So, I suggest you to just try to upload a random blank compressed zip file containing one file name same as the lambda function. It would give you the option to choose from both files, then choose for **"local"** file. It would take you to the in-line editor where your code was.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work anymore seemingly unfortunately

Comment: @Will what does not work?